# Desktop Metro applications

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I wonder how to create `Zune-like` apps (I mean `Metro` style). But I don't want them to be `Windows Store apps` (I have already installed `Windows 8` platform with `VS2012`). Could you tell me if I should download some style pack or something like that? Maybe there are some libraries implementing `Metro`? If yes, plese make me know which one is the best.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider WPF UI framweork for building apps like zune

http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Theme for WPF called Cosmopolitan](http://cosmopolitanwpf.codeplex.com/) that emulates the Metro style. Now it just gives you the flattened look on the controls for free. You're on your own with Layout, Animations, and Navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Due to naming issues (*read: MS didn't want to get sued and apparently couldn't properly trademark the word Metro, go figure*) there is no such thing as `Metro` anymore.

That style was renamed to be "Windows Store".  So I'm not 100% certain of what it is you are asking for.

Also, contrary to the name and potentially misleading marketing speak on their site, a Windows Store App does not have to be published and sold through the Windows Store.

You might read this for some "clarification":
 http://www.zdnet.com/microsoft-finally-comes-cleaner-on-post-metro-naming-plans-7000004151/

Comment: I want to create an app that looks like Zune. But I don't want it to be Windows Store app, because it should work on the normal desktop (exactly like Zune):)

Comment: Yes, the app type was renamed to Windows Store app.  But AFAIK, the UX design guidelines are still known as Metro-style.

Comment: This is such a non answer. He says he wants to create an app that looks like Zune and you're going into semantics about "there's no metro style". Almost sounds like Mitt during the debates "I'm glad you asked that question, because I'm going to give an answer that is only tangentially related to it"

Comment: @MikeBrown:  He's on Win8 and wants to develop a Win8 app.  That style is called "Windows Store App".  The OP appears to be confused that this would require him to publish it through the Windows Store which is not true.  Further, there have been changes to the lifecycle of apps that run under Win8, enough that just copying the UI elements aren't enough and he will be much better served by using the appropriate template.  Although this concept isn't as difficult as following any politicians words, it was made confusing by the screwed up naming that MS is currently employing.

Comment: No he want's to make a desktop app that follows the Windows Store UI Style (similar to Zune).

Comment: @MikeBrown: You haven't tried developing a Win8 app yet have you?

Comment: I'm actually developing one now. But I would like to retract my earlier statement. It comes across much more harshly than I intended. As I understand it, the OP wants to create a Desktop application (not windows store app) that looks like Zune. So "Metro Style" or "Modern UI" or whatever they're calling it now but in a desktop app.